# Prevent Login Screen from showing when auto login

Tags: ios, swift

I have implemented the auto login within my app into the viewcontroller linked to the Login View Controller. However, given below, the storyboard navigates to the Login screen first after the launcher screen. When there are credentials found in the keystore, the app will auto login, but the `Login` screen will still flash before then moving on.

[image]

How can I ensure the login screen will not appear if the user credentials are already in the keystore and navigate directly to the `Reveal View Controller`?

Comment: show your full stroyboad scene

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Store the user details in your loginScreen

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject("\(userNameTxtField.text!)", forKey: "userName")  
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

> 2. Put this function in your appDelegate

```
 func userIsLoggedIn() {
              let userName = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("userName")
              if userName != nil {
    //Navigate to Reveal View Controller
                }
            }
```

> 3. Then call the function in ViewDidFinishLauchingWithOption(In AppDelegate)

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
userIsLoggedIn()         
return true

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Complement to the @Kerby Jean answer. First remove the entry point in the storyBoard, assign the point by code in your app delegate at `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method, something like this:

```
UIWindow * window

var storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

//Slect initial viewController
self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds)
UIViewController * viewController
var preferences: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
var userId: String = preferences["userId"]

if userId != nil {
    viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NavigationController")
}
else {
    viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginViewController")
}
self.window.rootViewController = viewController
self.window.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Comment: I attempted this, the error resulted: `Failed to instantiate the default view controller for UIMainStoryboardFile 'Main' - perhaps the designated entry point is not set?`

Comment: Yes, I see always that warning but I dont see that that afects the performance.